# Using a normal router with SDSL

Tags: router, adsl

Possibly stupid question: can I use a regular router (in facts its a Netgear Firewall) with an SDSL connection?

This of course works fine with an ADSL connection. I know its all xDSL but is the tech. different enough to mean my hardware may not be compatible?

Comment: It's just a router or a router/modem where you attach the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal router should work fine, as long as you are not expecting it to do the physical layer SDSL connection.  Connection would be:

SDSL Equipment -- Router -- LAN

I only say this because it is so common to find combined ADSL modem, router, switch, firewall thought of as just an ADSL router.  I have seen a router (ASA 5505) do the PPoE negotation which would normally be handled by the ADSL equipment, but the ADSL modem was still required.

Aside - is "ADSL modem" the correct name for the bit that talks to the phone line?

Comment: Yes, the bit that talks to the phone line it's in fact a modem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, just ask for a modem with ethernet interface. Here many SDSL/HDSL router supplied by ISPs have still a v35/v36 serial interface.